# display dql Result with join in twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

how can i get access to the attributes from the joined table list in twig?

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT e, 
            l            
            FROM AcmeDemoBundle:entry e
            JOIN e.fklist l            
            WHERE e.fkuser=:user'
        );
```

This is the created query:

```
SELECT p0_.pkId AS pkId0, p0_.firstname AS firstname1, ...., 
p1_.pkId AS pkId13, p1_.descriptionAlt AS descriptionAlt14, ... 
FROM entry p0_ INNER JOIN list p1_ ON p0_.fkList = p1_.pkId 
WHERE p0_.fkUser = ? LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

I need access to the attributes in twig:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{entry. ...}}
            </td>
            <td>{{entry.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.firstname}}</td>                 
            </td>            
        </tr>       
    {% endfor %}
```

i have no idea how to get access to the attributes from the joined table without setting every single attribute with an own alias.

Comment: Have you tried simply `{{entry.descriptionAlt}}`?

Comment: ... or `{{entry.fklist.descriptionAlt}}`

Comment: Yes I've tried .the first gives me an error that this attribute is not in the object event and the second is the part that i will avoid because this generates automatically new queries to read the data what i would like to read with my join.

Comment: `...  because this generates automatically new queries`

Are you sure? Try your query in `app/console doctrine:query:dql` and you will see that it returns not only entry but associated entry.fklist too. Ergo, probably, it won't generate new queries.

Comment: sorry, wrong explanation. I need an attribute from the list entity that is a relationship column. when i need data from this related object, then its creating new queries.

Comment: Then add that relation to your query as well.  The idea is to pull in everything you need in one query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the result of the query to the Twig template!
Here, you never query your database.

See [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats) to find the best method, but getResult() seems to suit your needs. Then access your property like :

```
{{ entry.firstname }}
```